# coding for email address validation in xamarin.android visual studio 2015?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android, email-address

what is the coding of email address validation using C# in xamarin.android visual studio 2015 and also tell me if any name space is requried? please tell me all the imp step as well as coding for email address validation in edittext.
i am new in android.xamarin..  guys please help me

Answer (score 6):

You can use Regex for email validation.

First add following using statement

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

And after that use following helper method for validation:

```
Regex EmailRegex = new Regex (@"^([\w\.\-]+)@([\w\-]+)((\.(\w){2,3})+)$");
public bool ValidateEmail(string email)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(email))
        return false;

    return EmailRegex.IsMatch(email);
}
```

**Option 2:**

`Xamarin.Android` has a helper method for email validation you also use that:

```
Android.Util.Patterns.EmailAddress.Matcher(email).Matches();
```

Comment: sir Thankyou for your rep .but when  i tried this code give me a list of error they are as follow: 1` The modifier 'readonly' is not valid for this item App12
2, The type or namespace name 'Regex' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
3,The type or namespace name 'Regex' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: Remove `readonly` modifier and add following using statement on top of file: `using System.Text.RegularExpressions;`

Comment: sir, i created a new class for this function .can u please tell me how we can call this function to my SignUpactivity in `if()` condition

Comment: If you have added that in new class first you need to mark that function `ValidateEmail` & `EmailRegex` as `static`. After that you can use that as `YourClass.ValidateEmail(someTextField.Text)`

Comment: id this coding `{if (mtxtEmial.Text == emailaddressValidation.ValidateEmail(string email)){}` is correct?

Comment: no. call this way `if (emailaddressValidation.ValidateEmail(mtxtEmial.Text)) { }`

Comment: sir can u please tell me Regex  valitadion function for password ,phone no, address and name in an edittext

Comment: Good basis, but not entirely correct (e.g. the local part of the email address nowadays also permits various (other) non-alphanumeric characters like `+`, `$`, `%` and the likes).